# Export/Importing Expression Engine Entries

Tags: import, export, expressionengine

I'm currently building an Expression Engine site and have got to the stage when I would like to put it on a staging area for the client to see and start adding content too. However, if he starts adding content I'm not sure how to copy that over to my dev area before I do another update. I've had a look round for some import/export plugins but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do it, the best way I've seen so far is to export it using a statement within this plugin:

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/export

And import it again using this plugin:

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab

Is there a better way?

Comment: If your comment doesn't get the attention you were hoping for here consider posting it in http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The way I work is the dev database (or live database if the site is live) is always treated as the most up to date. Before any piece of work starts we download the whole live db and insert it locally. Any db changes you make get marked down and you manually apply them to live later. It's the only way to be sure you're not going to lose any data.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That's the only way -- major failing of ExpressionEngine. Control panel used to have an export option built in under 'Tools', but it was removed for reasons unknown!